# MySQL Query for Similar Column Value

Tags: mysql

In my database table, Due to some mistake same row has been entered twice, But it is now having one column value with some appended numeric value in the duplicate entry.

For example,
If my table has a column named `filename`, Then in one row it has value '**some-random-name.pdf**'.

And in the duplicate row, it has value '**some-random-name-1532.pdf**'.

I need to identify all such records. Please note that there can be any or zero number of dash(-) in the filename. So Like query something like `'%-____-%.pdf` did not help me.

Comment: You can add the queries you've tried so far in the question to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that complete filename contains only one dot between name and extension you may try this:

```sql
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.value, '.', -1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.value, '.', -1)
  AND LOCATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.value, '.', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.value, '.', 1)) = 1
```